# Add new page menu items misbehaving

Tags: sharepoint-online, new-experience

On SPO the cog menu item "Add new page" seems to create a new Site page even though I have deleted that page type in the Pages library!!!
Is there any way to get that menu item to behave,  or are we stuck with the "Microsoft are promoting their shiny new toys"  behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable it entirely, try it as below:

1. Navigate to the SharePoint admin center.
2. Click settings>selecting Prevent users from creating Site Pages under Site Pages.

   [image]

Note it may take some time to take effect(approx 24 hours).

But if you want to use both the modern pages and classic pages in SharePoint Online, then I think you can achieve that via the following steps.

a. Navigate to a library.

b. Click Return to classic SharePoint>Settings>Site contents>Site Pages>New to create a classic page.

c. If you click Settings>Add a page, you can still create a modern page.

[Classic Site Pages in 365](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10/classic-site-pages-in-365/1e9d0350-3820-4f37-9fcf-0ed9f019af88?page=1)